# Mongodb referenced document giving empty array after using populate

Tags: typescript, mongodb, reference

I have created a BlogPost schema with a referenced child comment. When I try to save the BlogPost, it saves with no error but when I retrieve the BlogPost using populate for the reference document, it produces an empty array. I am testing my code using supertest and jest.
Please help!!

Please find my code below

Post schema

```
import mongoose, { Mongoose } from 'mongoose';
import {CommentDoc} from './comment'


interface PostAttribs {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    userId: string;
    comment: CommentDoc;

}

interface PostDoc extends mongoose.Document {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    userId: string;
    comment: CommentDoc;
 }

interface PostModel extends mongoose.Model<PostDoc> {
    build(attribs:PostAttribs): PostDoc
    
}

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },

    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },
    comment: [{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment',
        required: false
    }]

    

    
}, {
    toJSON:{
        transform(doc, ret){
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret._id;
        }
    }
});

postSchema.statics.build = (attribs: PostAttribs)=>{
    return new Post(attribs);
};

const Post = mongoose.model<PostDoc,PostModel>('Post',postSchema);

export {Post};
```

Comment Schema

```
import mongoose, { Mongoose } from 'mongoose';


interface CommentAttribs {
    content: string;
    createdDt: Date;
}

export interface CommentDoc extends mongoose.Document {
    content: string;
    createdDt: Date;
 }

interface CommentModel extends mongoose.Model<CommentDoc> {
    build(attribs:CommentAttribs): CommentDoc
    
}

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },

    createdDt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true

    },

    
}, {
    toJSON:{
        transform(doc, ret){
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret._id;
        }
    }
});

commentSchema.statics.build = (attribs: CommentAttribs)=>{
    return new Comment(attribs);
};

const Comment = mongoose.model<CommentDoc,CommentModel>('Comment',commentSchema);

export {Comment};
```

CreatePost route

```
import express from 'express';
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import {body} from 'express-validator';
import {requireAuth, validateRequest, NotFoundErr} from '@pcblog/common';
import {Post} from '../models/posts';
import {Comment} from '../models/comment';
import {PostCreatedPublisher} from '../events/publishers/post-created-publisher';
import {natsWrapper} from '../nats-wrapper';


const createpost_router = express.Router();

createpost_router.post('/api/posts',requireAuth,[
    body('title').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Title is required'),
    body('content').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Content is required')
    
],validateRequest,async (req : Request,res : Response) => 
    {
        const {title,content,comment}=req.body;
        console.log('ye ppa',comment[0]);

        const commentB = Comment.build({
            content: req.body.comment[0].content,
            createdDt: req.body.comment[0].createdDt
        });
        
        const post = Post.build({
            title,
            content,
            userId: req.currentUser!.id,
            comment: commentB
        });
        
        console.log('Post after build',post);
        
        console.debug('Extracted comment:',post.comment);
        await post.save(function(err,data){
            console.log('Saved data',data)
        });
        console.log('Post before send',post);
        res.status(201).send(post);
        
    });

export {createpost_router as createPostRouter};
```

CreatePost.test.ts

```
import request from 'supertest';
import {post_app} from '../../app';
import {Post} from '../../models/posts';
import {Comment} from '../../models/comment';
import {natsWrapper} from '../../nats-wrapper';



it('when valid inputs are provided, create a post', async () => {
    let posts = await Post.find({});
    /*expect (posts.length).toEqual(0);
    await request(post_app)
        .post('/api/posts')
        .set('Cookie',global.signintoapp())
        .send({
            title: 'my title',
            content: 'my content',
            comment: [
            ]
        })
        .expect(201);*/
        const resp1=await request(post_app)
        .post('/api/posts')
        .set('Cookie',global.signintoapp())
        .send({
            title: 'my title',
            content: 'my content',
            comment: [
                {
                    content:'hi',
                    createdDt:20230101
                }
            ]
        })
        .expect(201);
    
    posts = await Post.find({});
    console.log('Size of posts: ',posts.length);
    expect (posts.length).toEqual(1);
    console.log('Response body',resp1.body);
    const prd = await Post.findById(resp1.body.id).populate('comment');
    console.log('The Post',prd);


});
```

The output that I get is this object

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("63dbd1256b55ccf04ed21db4"),
    title: 'my title',
    content: 'my content',
    userId: '63dbd1256b55ccf04ed21db2',
    comments: [],
    __v: 0
 }
```